# How can I calculate condition number in faster way?

Tags: performance, matlab, conditional-statements, svd

I am doing an optimization in MATLAB for calculating a condition number as below:

```
s = svd(H, 0);
cond = max(s) ./ min(s);
```

is very time consuming especially for large `H` matrix. I am looking for something approximate but fast.

Comment: What sizes of `H` are we talking about?

Comment: is `cond(H)` faster for you? That is the built in function... See http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/cond.html

Comment: the size of H depends on the system, but for system I am currently working on it is (300,300) and it is sparse but not semi-diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

You're calculating all the singular values and discarding all but two of them. You could try this instead:

```
largestS = svds(H,1); %largest singular value
smallestS  = svds(H,1,0); %smallest singular value
cond = largestS/smallestS
```

Comment: FYI, `cond` is a built-in function in MATLAB. I'd suggest using a different variable name.

Comment: The cond built-in function is performing the same routine with additional condition checking, so it takes more time.

Comment: And the svds(H,1) and svds(H,1,0) takes much much greater time to calculate the condition number.